# Nexus 10 cannot sign into Google Accounts

Tags: google-account, samsung-nexus-10

I have a brand new Nexus 10.  It worked for a few minutes of web browsing and then I am not sure what I did but somehow it got to the point where I was asked to sign into a Google Account.  Since I use `gmail`, the required answer to the question: `do you use Google Accounts?` is yes.  So I touched 'yes'.

I put in my gmail address and password.  Now it shows `Couldn't sign in, Can't establish a reliable connection to the server.`  There is the suggestion that it is a temporary problem but retries have failed over several days.

I then wiped all user data using instructions I found on the internet.  However, it still ends up stuck on the screen that shows `Couldn't sign in, Can't establish a reliable connection to the server.`

I even logged out of `gmail` on my laptop, but it doesn't help the situation on the Nexus 10.  The Nexus 10 is a brick so now I am shopping for a few hundred thousand of these and some mortar.

Additional info: I use 2-step verification on the laptop for my `gmail`.

Comment: I had a similar issue once. As soon as I switched networks, the issue solved itself (while the trouble was going on, I was permanently connected to my home WiFi -- after the network switch, it worked well in my home WiFi as well when re-connected). Worth a try, I'd say.

Comment: Did you check this thread? [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24979/persistent-google-sign-in-error-even-with-correct-password?rq=1). And, I know you wouldn't want this, but posting for others who'd want the same.[XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2110225)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reconfigured the router to resolve the problem.  The settings that work include:

- `g` rather than the other options being `b` and `g/n`.  This looks like the setting for the suffix on 802.11.
- WPA-Personal
- AES

Of course other settings may also work and might be more secure but I did not try them.