# Frequent "Google sign-in" error

Tags: google-account

On my Android device, I have added three Google accounts, and probably on average of once (or even twice) per week, all three accounts will have "Google sign-in" errors to show me. Unlike [the question about the persistent sign-in errors](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24979/2276), once I enter the correct password, the authentication succeeds, and the error vanishes, only to appear a week later.

I am not doing anything to change any of these accounts, but I am just using them normally on other PCs and devices. None of my other Android devices seem to have this problem. I am not using two-factor authentication.

Error dialog text:

- [English] Google sign-in: You entered the wrong password or your
  account has changed. Please re-enter your password.

What might I be doing to cause these errors and more importantly, how do I prevent these errors?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a cache problem since it's only on that device and not seemingly tied to the accounts themselves (since the problem is not elsewhere). Have you tried deleting the accounts from the device and then re-installing them? This can be a PIA if you have things like movies downloaded because - in my experience - it forgets where they are on the device and wants a re-download.

Comment: One of the accounts is the "base" Google account I've linked with my phone, meaning that the device would require a factory reset if I removed it. I would hope to find a way to clear the cache without a factory reset.

Comment: I've not had a problem removing all of the google accounts from a phone (no reset required), but of course YMMV.